# Why is no cloud allowed in this brief?

Tags: cloud-computing

I couldn't find a better place on StackExchange for this question, but please point me in the right direction if there is a better place for it.

My company is bidding for some work, and in the invitation to quote (under the Data Protection section) they state that there can be no "public or private cloud elements" to our solution.

This has baffled me - does anyone have any idea what they might have against using cloud servers (and, presumably, other products like a CDN)?

Comment: Have you tried asking the client?

Comment: There's a plethora of possible reasons for their decision, but we're unlikely to answer with all that they might have had. There are security implications, yes, but then again there's also non-security reasons that might be driving them to an in-house solution, like manageability, regulations compliance,... or even just personal quirks of the client. Since we can't be expected to answer that and is too subjective, I'm voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Not everybody likes having their data in plain on untrusted third party hosted servers.

Comment: Because there might be granite hanging out in that cloud. Nobody can guarantee that there's workable terrain avoidance, so the only way to avoid controlled flight into terrain is to avoid flying in clouds. Also avoiding flying into clouds means you automatically avoid strong airframe deforming updrafts and lightning. Not everyone is starry eyed over the cloud.

Comment: @iszi - Heh, being baffled shows lack of communications, something I really worry about in bidding. It gets pretty costly.

Comment: Don't want their product running in a shared memory space?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons to be against cloud. First, cloud is a meaningless marketing phrase. Whenever you want to have a real technical discussion at least use IaaS, PaaS, SaaS, etc. so we have some idea of what you are actually talking about. Second, I won't store my stuff in the cloud. Especially after all of the revelations about the NSA compromising all of the cloud providers by sniffing their inter-datacenter connections etc. Third, you have no idea what security controls are being employed and I've never seen a single cloud provider that would actually tell you. There are many more...